# How To Get Tab Text in GWT?

Tags: gwt

how do I get the text of a selected tab in GWT? I see there is a method com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TabBar.setTabText(String text) but how do I get the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extending TabPanel like so:

```
package com.benhowden.gwttemplate;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TabPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DFSTabPanel extends TabPanel {

List<String> tabsTexts;

public DFSTabPanel() {
    super();
    tabsTexts = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public void add(Widget w, String tabText) {
    super.add(w, tabText);
    tabsTexts.add(tabText);
}

@Override
public boolean remove(int index) {

    boolean removed =  super.remove(index);
    if(removed) {
       tabsTexts.remove(index);
       return removed;
    }

    return removed;

}

@Override
public void clear() {
    super.clear();
    tabsTexts.clear();
}

public String getTabText(int index) {
    return tabsTexts.get(index);
}

}
```